# Blinking issue in new chrome and opera versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have strange problem with blinking in chrome and opera after browser update. My site is build of divs which overlapse one on the another. During this overlapse, div which is overlapsed is blured. To do this I use 2 function.

```
     (function ($) {
        /* Store the original positions */
        var d1 = $('.one');
        var d1orgtop = d1.position().top;
        var d2 = $('.two');
        var d2orgtop = d2.position().top;


        /* respond to the scroll event */
        $(window).scroll(function () {
          /* get the current scroll position */
          var st = $(window).scrollTop();

          /* change classes based on section positions */
          if (st >= d1orgtop) {
            d1.addClass('latched');
          } else {
            d1.removeClass('latched');
          }
          if (st >= d2orgtop) {
            d2.addClass('latched');
            topbar_open();
          } else {
            d2.removeClass('latched');
          }


        });

      })(window.jQuery);


$(document).scroll(function () {
       var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        var pixels = scrollTop / 100;

        if (scrollTop < height) {
            $(".one").css({
                "-webkit-filter": "blur(" + pixels + "px)",
                "filter": "blur(" + pixels + "px)",
                "background-position": "center -" + pixels * 10 + "px"

            });

        }
}
```

Of course css class "latched" change position to fixed.

Ok, so my problem is that when I put video in one div, this div blink. This happend after chrome update. I found that blinking is connected with blur. Any ideas which can help me with this issue? Everything work fine before last chrome and opera updates.

Comment: The blink problem is because you're checking every time you scroll and then doing something based on that scroll. Change your conditional statement to check for the 'latched' class in addition to the scroll height before performing a function. This way the change has happened, it wont change back unless both conditions are met. That should resolve your blink issue.

Comment: I don't get it. Could explain this once again? Do you mean that I have to add this condition that check for 'latched' class in "if" in "scroll" function?

Answer (score 0):

Change your conditionals to something like this. What you're currently doing forces the browser to start over every time and then reapply the class which causes the blink. Adding a second condition means the browser wont do anything unless both conditions are met.

```
// Make sure that we've scrolled past the threshold and the latched class isn't already present.
if (st >= d1orgtop && ( !jQuery(".one").hasClass( "latched" ))) {

    // Add latched class 
    d1.addclass("latched");

// Check to see if we haven't scrolled past the threshold and if the latched class present.
} else if (st <= d1orgtop && ( jQuery(.one).hasClass( "latched" ))) {

    // Remove latched class
    d1.removeClass("latched");
}
```

Then attach your blur to your number classes and have the latched class be the non blurred class.

Alternatively, you may be able to achieve something like this through CSS by delaying the time before a transition happens. It's a little risky, if it works, though.

```
.latched {
    -webkit-transition-delay: .5s;
    transition-delay: .5s;
}
```